# neo4j rest api send multiple query and parameters

Tags: java, json, rest, groovy, neo4j

Currently have built out in HttpBuilder:

```
def static query(statement, params,success, error, String _URL)
{
    def http = new HTTPBuilder( _URL )
    http.request( Method.POST, ContentType.JSON ) {
        uri.path = '/db/data/cypher'
        headers.'X-Stream' = 'true'
        requestContentType = ContentType.JSON
        body =  [ query : statement , params : params ?: [:] ]

        // uri.query = [ param : 'value' ]

        response.success = { resp, json ->
            if (success) success(json)
            else {
                println "Status ${resp.statusLine} Columns ${json.columns}\nData: ${json.data}"
            }
        }

        response.failure = { resp, message ->
            def result=[status:resp.statusLine.statusCode,statusText:resp.statusLine.reasonPhrase]
            result.headers = resp.headers.collect { h -> [ (h.name) : h.value ] }
            result.message = message
            if (error) {
                error(result)
            } else {
                println "Status: ${result.status} : ${result.statusText} "
                println 'Headers: ${result.headers}'
                println 'Message: ${result.message}'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which can take in one query statement and one parameters map and spit out a response from the server.  However I would like to input an array of queries and parameters (Such as a json array of each).  I have tried looping through a json object in the body but to no avail.  Any thoughts? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Neo4j 2.0 introduced a new "[transactional HTTP endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-transactional.html)". One of its capabilities is to pass in multiple cypher statements and multiple parameter sets. It's very well documented, so I suggest giving it a try.

Alternatively you can use [batch operations](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-batch-ops.html) to aggregate multiple calls to the "old" endpoint (`/db/data/cypher`). However I'd suggest the first approach.

Comment: So do I just need to loop through a JsonArray of the statements?   Not sure how to structure of the `body` of the `HttpBuilder`

Comment: `statements` is an array. It's elements are maps consisting of `statement` and `parameters` entries. See https://gist.github.com/sarmbruster/9056261 for an example. This uses only 1 statement, but you should be able to adopt it easily.